# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'CLLocationDegrees?' (aka 'Optional<Double>')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hey guys I'm getting this error in this block of code:

```
 @IBAction func requestGroomrButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if pickUpNotificationOn == false {

        var locationForRider = ["Latitude": self.latitude, "Longitude": self.longitude]


        let fireUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        locationForRider["Email"] = fireUser!.email <-ERROR HERE
```

The error is on the last line and says: Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'CLLocationDegrees?' (aka 'Optional')

Here is my fireUser variable:

```
if let fireUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
      FirebaseData.fb.REF_BASE.child(PICKUP_NOTIFICATION).child(fireUser.uid).observe(.value, with: {snapshot in

            if snapshot.hasChild("driverAccepted") {

                FirebaseData.fb.REF_BASE.child(DRIVER_LOCATION).child(fireUser.uid).observe(DataEventType.value, with: {driverSnapshot in

                    if let snapshots = driverSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

                        for snap in snapshots {
                            if let dLat = snap.value["driverLat"] as? Double {
                                self.driverLatitude = dLat
                            }
                            if let dLong = snap.value["driverLong"] as? Double {
                                self.driverLongitude = dLong
                            }
```

EDIT: I'm using Swift 4, and latest version of Xcode (Xcode 9)

Comment: Are you sure that `self.latitude` and `self.longitude` is `Double`?

Comment: `var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0` `var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0` @RashwanL

Comment: @Adeel you should choose better your dictionary name. locationForRider holds also email info and thats very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: The compiler infers the type of the dictionary `locationForRider` as `[String:CLLocationDegrees]`. If you want to have a heterogenous dictionary you have to annotate the type as `[String:Any]`

```
var locationForRider : [String:Any] = ["Latitude": self.latitude, "Longitude": self.longitude]
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler infers the type of `locationForRider` to be of type `[String: CLLocationDegrees]`. And then later you try to set a value of `String`, which is not possible.

You should help the compiler by declaring the type of `locationForRider` to be `[String:Any]`:

````
var locationForRider: [String: Any] = ["Latitude": self.latitude, "Longitude": self.longitude]```
````

Comment: Thank you, you saved the day! Really appreciate you in taking the time to help solve this problem :)